# Split on multiple characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm doing this to split a string on pipes.

```
wordarray = comments.split("\\|");
```

I want that string to be split on both pipes and colons :

Is there a way I can combine those into command?
Something like:

```
wordarray = comments.split("\\|",":")
```

Note, i want it to split on all the occurences not just the first one

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you could also write your original line like this: `comments.split(Pattern.quote("|"))`.  Then you don't need to worry or think about escaping the `|` character; `quote` takes the String literally, and escapes anything it needs to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use character class for this. Consider this code:

```
String[] wordarray = comments.split("[|:]");
```

Comment: ah i see. do i not need to do \\| since | is a special character?
or is it because its inside the regex braces

Comment: Inside the character class you don't need to escape pipe and many more special regex characters.

Comment: ah cool going to test it out now! also to clarify split splits on all occurences not just the first one, right?